# Receiving a 404 error because npm install's request url is randomly adding the word "clear"

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, terminal, console

As seen in the code below, the url for the npm registry is https://registry.npmjs.org/clear/ionic when it should be https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic.  I've completely uninstalled node and npm, restarted my computer, and reinstalled, but I still get the same issue.  Although I couldn't install ionic and cordova before, this url issue only came about after a ran `clear` to clear my console.  I have no idea how that could have effected the registry url, however.

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/clear/ionic
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'clear' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/zacharymelancon/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by running

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```